# Load products page inside phtml page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, products, layered-navigation, phtml, custom-block

I have a custom **.phtml** page, and i want to insert products page which contain **layered navigation** like this:

[image: example]

so i already have filtered product collection, is there a chance to do call this **products page** with **layered navigation** in my **.phtml** file with **custom product collection**?

Comment: You must create product collection in a Block in a new module with filter, it's not best practice this.